# Drupal 7 - accessing content through url alias over ReST

Tags: rest, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a `Drupal` 7 with `Pathauto` and `restws` modules. I am able to configure `Pathauto` module to create a url alias for my content type so now the content that I could access with url http://mycms.org/mydrupal/node/4 is accessible using http://mycms.org/mydrupal/content/1-sampleID.

Also, I am able to access the content over `ReST` using http://mycms.org/mydrupal/node/4.json. 
However i need to access the content over `ReST` api using the url alias, say, http://mycms.org/mydrupal/content/1-sampleID.json. When I try doing this, I get a 404 error.

I am new to `Drupal` and `PHP`. Can someone please help me fix this issue? Do I need some custom `Drupal` module that could help me expose my contents over `ReST` api through the defined url aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the RESTful module, and [here's a blog post](http://smgaweb.com/blog/creating-restful-api-url-alias-lookup-drupal) on how to do what you need.